# How to clean my data and create a graph with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I want to create a graph using data from Wikipedia, I created a data frame out of table that I have found. It contains two columns - style of beer and range of bitternes (IBU) like "20-50". Both are character, so I can't make a graph out of it that makes sense. I managed to change IBU column to two separate ones that are both numeric (min and max) but it created second data frame inside my first data frame, tried to find similar case but I couldn't, I'm now stuck and don't know what to do next :(
Sorry in advance for pasting so much code, I just want someone to read the data and see it's structure.

```
library(xml2)
library(rvest)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

file_html <- read_html(
  "https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bittering_Units",
   encoding = "UTF-8")
table_html <- html_node(file_html, "#mw-content-text > div > table")
table_IBU <- html_table(table_html, fill = TRUE)


table_IBU$IBU2 <- str_replace(table_IBU$`Stopień IBU`, "\\+", "")
table_IBU$IBU3 <- tidyr::separate(table_IBU, IBU2, into = c("min", "max"), sep = " – ")
table_IBU <- subset(table_IBU, select = -c(IBU2,
                                          `Stopień IBU`,
                                          `Gatunek piwa`))

table_IBU$IBU3$min2 <- as.numeric(table_IBU$IBU3$min)
table_IBU$IBU3$max2 <- as.numeric(table_IBU$IBU3$max)

#graph that I can come up with on my own

IBUgraph <- ggplot(table_IBU$IBU3, aes(reorder(`Gatunek piwa`, + max2), 
                                 max2)) + 
  geom_point(width = 0.5, color = "darkolivegreen",
           fill = "darkseagreen4") + 
  theme(text=element_text(size = 9)) 
IBUgraph = IBUgraph +
  labs(y = "Międzynarodowe Jednostki Goryczy (IBU)",
       x = "Gatunek",
       title = "Skala IBU - International Bitterness Units, 
       czyli międzynarodowe jednostki goryczy")
IBUgraph <- IBUgraph + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1.1))

IBUgraph
```

In the end I want to create a graph using ggplot() showcasing style of beer on x axis, and two points for each style showcasing minimum vaule, maximum value.

Comment: Do you need a legend?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What ggplot code have you written so far?  Which aspects are you having trouble with?

Comment: @StupidWolf No, I do not need a legend

Comment: @wibeasley So in conclusion: Now I have 3 columns that I want to include, Style of beer, minimum value and maximum value for each style, and I only know how to include two columns. I'll edit my question and add some more code so you can see what kind of graph I can come out with on my own

Comment: *"Both are character, so I can't make a graph out of it that makes sense"* IBU range actually consists of two separate numeric columns e.g. "20-50", which you parse into IBU3$min,max with `separate()`, but you don't like its output format as a sub-dataframe/named list. Is that [`tidyr::separate()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate.html), or some other package?

Comment: your data structure is really weird. you needa sort it out. So you pull out the dataframe, df <- table_IBU$IBU3, and I have to rename the first column. colnames(df)[1] = "X", then plot like : ggplot(df,aes(x=X))+geom_point(aes(y=min2),col="orange") + geom_point(aes(y=max2),col="brown")+ xlab("Gatunek piwa")

Comment: @smci, yup, tidyr

Comment: @StupidWolf thank you, I know it's weird and I've been having trouble sorting it, I only know the basics in R and it's my first time creating a graph so I'm confused a little bit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this for example, it's called a dumbbell chart

```
ggplot(table_IBU$IBU3,aes(x=`Gatunek piwa`)) + 
      geom_point(aes(y=min2)) + # add point for min
      geom_point(aes(y=max2)) + # add point for max
      geom_segment(aes(xend=`Gatunek piwa`,y=min2,yend=max2)) + # create segment between min and max
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) # rotate x axis
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

So, are you looking for something like this?

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(rvest)

#Acquire table
table_IBU <- read_html("https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bittering_Units", encoding = "UTF-8") %>%
  html_node(., "#mw-content-text > div > table") %>%
  html_table(., fill = TRUE)

#Extract scores into min and max values
table_IBU$IBU2 <- str_replace(table_IBU$`Stopień IBU`, "\\+", "")
table_IBU %<>% separate(., IBU2, into = c("min", "max"), sep = " – ") %>% select(-c(`Stopień IBU`))
table_IBU$min <- as.integer(table_IBU$min)
table_IBU$max <- as.integer(table_IBU$max)
table_IBU %<>% gather(data = ., key = "Limit", value = "Value", min, max)

#Plot
table_IBU %>% ggplot(data = ., aes(x = `Gatunek piwa`)) + 
  geom_point(aes(y = Value, col = Limit)) + 
  xlab("Type of beer") +
  ylab("Score (0-120)") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image: RPlot]

Quite an odd way to display this data.